# AWS CodeBuild : Installed conda but not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, conda, aws-codebuild, miniconda

Aim: Activate miniconda environment

Code:

```
       - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
       - export CONDA_PREFIX=minicond
       - wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
       - bash Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $CONDA_PREFIX
       - conda activate base
```

Status:Failure
Error:

```
Running command conda activate base

/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: conda: not found
```

#### Other things tried

Failure
Error:

```
Running command source $CONDA_PREFIX/bin/activate

/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: source: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify bash as default shell in CodeBuild in `buildspec.yml`.

```
env:
  shell: bash
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax